# How to draw simple 3d axis in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mplot3d

[image]

I would like to have names of axes as in the figure.

Comment: Do you really need to have a 3d or something that just looks like a 3d plot. i.e. three line segments.

Comment: I really need 3d axis, then I will plot more into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a good starter. Try experiment with it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[8,8])
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

# some settings
vleng = 4
aleng = vleng/3.

p = np.array([vleng, 0, 0])
q = np.array([0, vleng, 0])
r = np.array([0, 0, vleng])

ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], p]).T, color='b')
ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], q]).T, color='g')
ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], r]).T, color='r')

# plotting arrow at terminal of the lines
ax.quiver(vleng, 0, 0, aleng, 0, 0,  \
          length=0.5, arrow_length_ratio=0.5, color='r')
ax.quiver(0, vleng, 0, 0, aleng, 0, \
          length=0.5, arrow_length_ratio=0.5, color='m')
ax.quiver(0, 0, vleng, 0, 0, aleng, \
          length=0.5, arrow_length_ratio=0.5, color='k')

ax.text3D(vleng+1.5, 0, 0, 'X')
ax.text3D(0, vleng+1.0, 0, 'y')
ax.text3D(0, 0, vleng+1.0, 'z')

ax.azim = 35    # y rotation (default=270)
ax.elev = 20    # x rotation (default=0)
ax.dist = 15    # zoom (define perspective)

ax.set_axis_off( )  # hide all grid
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# plot poly1
ax.plot3D( [3.5, 0.25, 2, 3.5], [1, 0.25, 2.5, 1], [1.9, 3.2, 3.8, 1.9], label = 'one line', color='pink' )
# projection of poly1 on xy-plane
ax.plot3D( [3.5, 0.25, 2, 3.5], [1, 0.25, 2.5, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], label = 'one line', color='gray' )
#ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I got this error: ` 'It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect '
NotImplementedError: It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect on 3D axes` What does it mean please?

Comment: 3D axes don't allow to set the aspect. That's what the error tells you about.